# Is it better to use ASIHTTPRequest to have iOS app communicate with the database server or write a web service (.NET or MVC Web API)?

Tags: ios, web-services, asihttprequest

I'm not sure what direction to go in setting up communication between my iOS app and the database server. I was convinced till this morning that I should write a .NET web service but then I read about ASIHTTPRequest and now I'm lost what to use.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by ".NET web service" you mean a SOAP interface, I strongly recommend against this. SOAP is a serious pain to manage on iOS. REST interfaces are much, much easier.

ASIHTTPRequest is no longer supported, and I don't recommend it for new projects. For REST protocols, I recommend [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit) or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). I have a bias for MKNetworkKit, but both are good frameworks.

Comment: So I can communicate directly with the database server from my iOS app without using any web service?

Comment: BTW, I just picked up your book and that where I read about ASIHTTPRequest.

Comment: You could, but that would take even more work. I recommend a REST service instead.

Comment: Yes, ASIHTTPRequest was discontinued around the time we were finishing the book. Mugunth is currently completely rewriting that chapter. http://iosptl.com/posts/mknetworkkit/

Comment: Thanks for your response. One more question - when would I want to use MKNEtworkKit in my iOS app?

Comment: MKNetworkKit is good for any REST-based protocol. It's particularly good when you have REST-based transactions that you'd like to queue while offline. It was designed to be a natural replacement for ASIHTTPRequest.

Comment: I'm not experienced in JAVA to write a REST service. Was kinda hoping there would be a way around. I guess not.